# Are certain weapons considered two-handed?

Tags: rimworld

One of my colonists is missing a hand. Let's not go into how it happened- suffice to say there were elephants. Getting him a bionic replacement could take a while.

Until then, I'd still like to use him for defence- he has a decent shooting skill. Does he need to use a pistol or other one-handed weapon, or are the penalties the same no matter what I give him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** 
Losing one hand doesn't effect the colonists base ability to aim/shoot the weapon. Losing a hand will only effect their manipulation. Losing two hands still doesn't effect the aiming and shooting time but they can no longer wield a weapon. As long as a colonist has one hand, he/she can use any weapon as usual.

**Long** 
I did some research into the question and ran some tests to see what effects loosing a hand has. The the current effect of loosing one hand is removing 50% of total manipulation. Loosing both hands completely removes all manipulation. When testing this the colonist dropped the weapon and could no longer pick up any weapon.

The colonist with one hand could still use all weapons but only has 50% manipulation. This has no effect on the aim/aiming time of the colonist. I tested this with both colonists and neither of their accuracy or aiming time stats where effected with the loss of hands. This stat can be seen in the information panel.

I've included some screenshots below showing the results of my tests. I did this via debug mode.

Screenshots 
[Rimworld Tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jCGc.jpg)

Comment: Great answer. I'm going to save the bounty for a few days in case something better is added but I doubt that'll happen.